# LESS: Unwanted property inheritance

Tags: css, less

I define the following:

```css
    ul.menu-level1 {

        li.menu-level1-item {
            font-size: @font-size-large;

            &.active {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }

    div.menu-level2 {

    }
```

```html
 <ul class="menu-level1">
  <li class="menu-level1-item"><a href="/">some</a></li>
  <li class="menu-level1-item has-submenu active"><a href="/">some</a>
   <div class="menu-level2">
    <ul>
     <li class="menu-level2-item"><a href="/">some</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

But still, the `menu-level2` items are getting `font-weight: bold`, because they inherit from `menu-level1`.

What am I doing wrong?

What I want to achieve: Only the `menu-level1-item active` elements should be bold, not all childs also.

EDIT: made `ul.menu-level2` to `div.menu-level2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `ul.menu-level2` is incorrect. You are assigning that `class` to `div` element and not `ul`, so it should be

```
div.menu-level2 {}
```

As far as the inheritance goes, you can do something like

```
ul.menu-level1 {
  li.menu-level1-item {
    font-size: @font-size-large;

    &.active {
      > a {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nesting an additional `a` will only restrict your `menu-level1` `a` tag to be `bold` and not the child elements.

If you don't want to do this, then you need to add another selector for `menu-level2` and specify `font-weight: normal;` for those `li` elements which you don't want to be bold, but I wouldn't recommend that.